# Xcode 7 - 'xxx' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer

Tags: ios, xcode7

My project need to support iOS 7 and above. So I wrote different code for iOS 7 and above, everything works fine. However, I just upgraded Xcode from 6.4 to 7.0, Xcode alert me 'xxx' is only available on iOS, even through the code won't execute on iOS 8 because I checked the iOS version before execute.

Is there any way to use Xcode 7 and support iOS 7 and above?

[image]

Comment: UIUserNotificationType, UIAlertController, UIAlertActionStyle, and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using swift or objective-c but there is a whole new availability checking functionality built into the language that allow you to add an

`@available` call in front of functions / methods to only call them on specific platforms:

Here is an overview link:
* https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking

```
@available(iOS 9, *)
func useStackView() {
    // use UIStackView
}
```

Is it possible you didn't `import UIKit` << this is likely what your issue might be?

That is usually the cause in your case

Answer (score 1):

and use availability check in if statement is like this

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, OSX 10.10, *) {
      //things to do
}
```